# Extracting what each package provides from a text file using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.4

it's has been a while since I was working on with this but I can't figure out how to resolve my problem.

I have multiple paragraphs such as in the Packages.gz file present in this link http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/

I would like your help to process it using a regular expression in order to get at the end a dictionary containing as keys the packages and values a list of the packages they provide.

As you can see, some packages do provide one or more packages others don't. My best regular expression was the following :

```
    ((?<=Package: ).*)|((?<=Provides: )(?:[, ]*[a-zA-Z0-9-+.]*))
```

It stops on the first package in the "Provides:" sentence, but I need them all without the ", ".

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the input string? What is the expected output?

Comment: Is '*using a regular expression*'  a definite requirement? Can you explain why you want to use an RE in this instance?

Comment: The input is the text file present on the link, the needed output as I saw on regex (using findall) is going to be a list of tuples containing the package name and the packages it might provide

Comment: RE is necessary because the amout of data to process is huge (more than 70000 lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program that builds a `dict` object to map "package" lines to `list`s representing "provides" lines.

It uses a regular expression, and `re.findall`, as requested.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

with open('Packages') as fp:
    data = fp.read()

data = re.findall(
    r'''
    (?smx)                  # Dot matches all, Multiline, Verbose
    ^Package:\s*(.*?)$      # The package line
    .*?                 #     Arbitrary lines
    (?:
        ^Provides:\s*(.*?$) # The provides line
        |                   # OR
        ^$                  #  an empty line
    )
    ''',
    data)

data = {k:v.split(',') if v else [] for k,v in data}

pprint(data)
```

Alternatively, here is a solution that does not use a regular expression. It runs slightly faster in my PC, on your 70,000-line file. The speed difference is largely irrelevant, however; the difference is less than .02 seconds.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

def gen():
    with open('Packages') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if line.startswith('Package:'):
                package = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            elif line.startswith('Provides:'):
                yield package, line.split(':')[1].strip().split(',')
                package = None
            elif package and line == '\n':
                yield package, []
                package = None
        if package:
            yield package, []

data = dict(gen())

pprint(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel here.  The [python-apt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python-apt) library already implements the text file parsing you want.  I recommend using it.  It will give you the list of [provides](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt.debfile.html#apt.debfile.DebPackage.provides) for a package.

Comment: To make sure I have understood your suggestion, do you mean that I use a regex to get the packages the apply the provides method to get the list I need ?

Comment: No.  I mean you don't need to deal with regexes at all, or with parsing, or lexing, or dealing with it at such a low level.  Just use the library to load the file. It will give you the list.